# How do I find the angle between two 3D vectors for camera orientation?

Tags: math, camera, rotation, directx-11

I'm currently trying to finish my camera orientation and have ran into a problem where I will need to compute the angle between two vectors in order to rotate my camera to look in my desired direction. Currently my camera always looks at 0,0,0 regardless of whether I specify a camera 'lookat'. I have found out that my camera will only rotate by increasing/decreasing the floats that I have stored (which is used when creating the rotation matrix).

I am trying to rotate around the Y axis only and for rotation I am using XMMatrixRotationAxisY(vector, #);

I have VectorA and VectorB.
**VectorA** = the current lookat position of the camera and **VectorB** = the desired lookat position of the camera

How do I compute the angle to pass into XMVectorRotationY, based on the two vectors above?

```
XMFLOAT3 currentDirection = XMFLOAT3(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
XMFLOAT3 destinationDirection = XMFLOAT3(200.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f);

rotationY = ?

XMMatrixRotationAxisY(vector, rotationY);
```

**?** being the angle we wish to rotate by

Comment: the vectors 1,0,1 and 100,0,100 point in the same exact direction.  They just have different length.

Comment: @MikeWodarczyk They are supposed to be world coordinates

Answer (score 0):

The cross product of two vectors v1, v2, produces another vector (v) perpendicular to the plane defined by the two other vectors. This (v) is the axis of your rotation.

The angle for rotation is arccosine of the dot product of vectors v1, v2.

You can compute the decomposition of (v) projecting into the plane needed, which can be easy with the dot product again.

Answer (score 0):

First, project these two vectors on XOZ (
v_proj = {dot(v,X),0,dot(v,Z)} where X,Y,Z are basis vectors and dot is dot product). Since you get current and destination vectors projected on XOZ,. normalize projections. Then find cos(theta) = dot(cur_proj, dest_proj).  Call acos for angle. Or you can construct rotation matrix by yourself.

Rot_y =

`cos(theta); 0; sin(theta);
0; 1; 0;
-sin(theta); 0; cos(theta)`

where sin(theta) = |cur_proj X dest_proj| - cross product. To get the sign you need to look at Y component of cross vector